# (Permanently) changing resolution in Elder Scrolls III: Morrowind

Tags: steam, the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

When I launch "Elder Scrolls III: Morrowind" from Steam, it pops up a launcher that looks like this:

[image: Launcher]

If I go into "Options", I can change the resolution from 1024x768 (default) to 1400x1050 (still tiny, but not as bad as the default):

[image: Changing resolution]

But when I start the game, it launches at 1024x768, and I have the go *back* into the Options from the main menu and reselect the resolution. My choices from the launcher don't appear to ever be honored, and my chosen resolution always resets between launches. (And since this game crashes to desktop often on Windows 10, constantly going into the Options menu and setting it becomes tedious.)

Is there some way to make this resolution sticky, possibly by futzing around with an ini file or maybe a Steam launcher commandline argument?

Comment: Not strictly speaking an answer to your question, but I can only recommend taking a look at the open-source engine reimplementation [OpenMW](https://openmw.org/en/), that is already feature-complete enough to allow playing the full game. It offers many more options than the original engine.

Comment: You didn't finish 'installing' Morrowind. - EXE's that should be in the directory when you're done: MGEXEgui, MWSE, MorrowindCodePatch. - And the only one that needs to run as administrator is the patch. - Disable Steam Overlay, or even better, don't use Steam.

Comment: @Mazura I have no idea what you're talking about. I don't play with mods on initial play through and afaik those never shipped with the game.

Comment: Same as the answer below except forgo FPS, and add the patch. Might as well set up for mods with MWSE because MGEXE is going to ask you where that is when you install it. "this game crashes to desktop often on Windows 10" - not on mine, with all of that.

Comment: For playing the base game without mods, OpenMW is excellent, as it is the same, but with no loading/lag and stuff like scaling and modern resolutions. Just drop the EXE in the folder and launch from that, afaik.

Comment: There's a difference between *vanilla*, and *vanilla, patched, with 20y worth of quality of life improvements* (the only mods I'm running are esthetic) and "modded". If you want to play it like I did in 1999 then... wait no, I can't let you do that to yourself. You at least need *distant land* (MGE - which 'needs' those other things) - and then this becomes a Q/A of **How to run Morrowind on W10**.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't know why the launcher settings aren't getting saved, but I can imagine Steam somehow obstructs this.

In any case, the resolutions of Morrowind are set in its registry entry — not in an *.ini* file — so changing it is a bit harder than editing a straightforward(ish) text file.

Still, the steps are provided [here](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Technical_Information#Resolution_and_Aspect_Ratio#Resolution_and_Aspect_Ratio):

> You can also set any custom resolution by hand: (Note that Morrowind must be fully launched at least one time for these registry settings to be viewable)
>
> Press Windows+R on keyboard, then type `regedit` in the box that opens.
> Locate the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Bethesda Softworks\Morrowind` (for 64-bit Windows system, locate `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Bethesda Softworks\Morrowind`).
> On the right pane, you will see several numerical values. Double-click on "*Screen Height*" and "*Screen Width*", and set them to values you wish to use (e.g. `1050` and `1400`, respectively).
>
> In Windows 7 64-bit, these same registry values can be found at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VirtualStore\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Bethesda Softworks\Morrowind`.

Do note that without any third-party mods or plugins the game will only allow for 4:3 aspect ratios.

To circumvent that limitation, and make the entire process easier, there are some plugins that give you a graphic interface to tweak these and many more settings:

- Morrowind Graphics Extender XE ([NexusMods](https://www.nexusmods.com/morrowind/mods/41102)).
- Morrowind FPS Optimizer ([PC Gaming Wiki](https://community.pcgamingwiki.com/files/file/74-morrowind-fps-optimizer/)/[NexusMods](https://www.nexusmods.com/morrowind/mods/3875)).

---

Also, take a look at [this post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/22320/discussions/0/152391995418025892/#c152391995418185670) and [this guide](https://wiki.nexusmods.com/index.php/Morrowind_graphics_guide). The first one is for general optimizations, the second to overhaul and mod the graphics. It's unrelated to the question, but might dramatically improve your experience.

Comment: MGE XE needs "[Morrowind Code Patch](https://www.nexusmods.com/morrowind/mods/19510) if you want to use MWSE." (which you have dig up on github these days) which does *not* work with OpenMW (meaning you can *either* have that, or basically every other mod that exists - you kinda have to decide that while you're installing MGE) - I don't use FPS anymore. I got distant land to work again (after a fresh install) and a few mods going, and it works fine. But I definitely have better than "Any graphics card made since 2009 or so" - OP's card is Intel HD360 from 2016.